# How to find word tokens inside of unbroken string, such as username, in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, nlp, nltk

I am trying to find and count the number of tokens that resemble words inside of strings that look like usernames. That is, strings unbroken by obvious stop words or spaces. So if the username was 'blackmagics1221' then if I used my code

```
def tokenizer():
    #a functoin to tokenize unbroken strings
 x=tokenizer('blackmagics1221')
```

when tokenized I should get `x=['black','magic']`, and `len(x)=2`.

'truck_$$$' should give `x=['truck']`, and `len(x)=1`. I tried to use nltk.word_tokenizer(), but it simply finds the entire string to be one token. An even better solution would look at number and spelling substations, but that would be more advances. In that case

```
x=tokenizer('ca$h_money_123')
```

would yield `x=['ca$h', 'money']`, ideally, or `x=['cash','money']`, which would be okay but not great. Any help would be appreciated! My searches on SO and google have come up short so far.

I have tried

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
s='caraaabbb1111'
test1= nltk.word_tokenize(s)
Out:'caraaabbb1111'
```

I want this to return(['car'])

and

```
wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
test2=wnl.lemmatize(s)
Out:'caraaabbb1111'
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details as per the How to Create a [mcve] page. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: I edited to reflect your comment. I felt that this may have been a more process oriented question, because my code doesn't even come close. I was hoping that there is a library in python which already does this, but I can't find one.

Comment: tokenizers work differently - they tokenize based on spaces and punktuation - you would need a tokenizer based on potential english words. Does nltk provide such a one? f.e one with `car` and `carrot` for `abracarrotdabra` ... what did your research find in that direction?=

Comment: nltk does have a word tokenize and a lemmatizer that both work in English. The starting point for me would be to focus on English.